# How to set Selenium Webdriver using Internet Explorer Browser to not share sessions during multi threaded testing

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I'm trying to test against Internet Explorer 11 multi-threaded using selenium webdriver with IEDriverServer.exe.

I can now launch multi-threaded IE browsers and interact with it but it seems that all of the IE browsers that were launched shared the same session and login.

For example I'm testing gmail site.

- 1st browser thread launches gmail home page > logins at gmail site
- 2nd browser thread launches gmail home page. Gmail already logged in.

How can I set internet explorer 11 to have its own session?

I've tested on mozilla firefox and I don't have this issue/situation.

Hope somebody can help and give me a definite answer

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by launching IE in private mode

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();  
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.FORCE_CREATE_PROCESS, true);  
сapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_SWITCHES, "-private");
InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

Please make sure that your registry has the below property and value else you will get an exception:-

Open the registry editor and go to the section below and locate the **TabProcGrowth** key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main
```

If the key exist, make sure to change the value to 0 else  create a new DWORD (32-bit) Value or String Value and name it as TabProcGrowth.

Set the value of the **TabProcGrowth** key to 0.